# With TMS TDBAdvGrid, how to color lines with different colors depending on cell values?

Tags: delphi, tms

All is in the title.
How can we also make an officehint customisable for each row. Mean when mousemove on a row, display the information of this record (from a db query).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can color individual cells using the `CellProperties` property of the grid. You can use this to color an entire row:

```
var
  RowIndex: Integer;
  ColIndex: Integer;

with MyDBAdvGrid do
begin
  // you choose the row index; you may want to iterate all rows to 
  // color each of them
  RowIndex := 2;
  // now iterate all (non-fixed, visible) cells in the row and color each cell
  for ColIndex := FixedCols to ColCount - 1 do
  begin
    CellProperties[ColIndex, RowIndex].BrushColor := clYellow;
    CellProperties[ColIndex, RowIndex].FontColor := clGreen;
  end;
end;
```

To fill your office hint with record data I would suggest updating it when the user moves the mouse. Use the `MouseToCell` function to get row and column under the mouse, then use `MyDBAdvGrid.AllCells[ColIndex, RowIndex]` to access the cell content.

Comment: Thanks for it, but when u tell the CellPropierties, mean on which event ?

Comment: Some event indicating data change. This depends on how you use your grid. There are so many events on this thing...

Answer (score 0):

An Alternative to Heinrich answer is to use the `OnGetCellColor` event.

This can be use like so:

```
procedure TDBAdvGrid.DBGridGetCellColor(Sender: TObject; ARow,
  ACol: Integer; AState: TGridDrawState; ABrush: TBrush; AFont: TFont);
begin
     if (your condition) then ABrush.Color := clRed;
end;
```

Similarly for the hint:

```
procedure TDBAdvGrid.DBGridGridHint(Sender: TObject; ARow, ACol: Integer;
  var hintstr: String);
begin
    hintstr := 'your hint text';
end;
```

Comment: THanks, but in that way it only display the color when i click the row.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same seems without moving my cursor ? Thakns

Comment: You may need to take into account the AState property.